# How to set Focus after animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to set focus on a textbox of id let's say txtName after scrolling to top of page using div.focus and animate().

Is there a functionality that specifies to focus after animate like document.ready would perform after document.ready?

The code I used to scroll is given below.

```
$(".gototop").click(function(){ 
    var focusElement = $("#contents"); 
    $(focusElement).focus(); 
    ScrollToTop(focusElement); 
}); 

function ScrollToTop(el) { 
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(el).offset().top - 50 }, 'slow');           
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set focus to an element in animate's callback, that way it will receive focus when the animation is completed:

```
function ScrollToTop(el) { 
    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $(el).offset().top - 50 }, 
    'slow', function() {
        $("#txtName").focus();
    });           
}
```

and if `el` is the element you wish to focus, you can use the passed variable instead of `#txtName`

Comment: You beat me to it. @Archie Dave, see the jQuery docs for animate, where the "complete" parameter is the function to call when the animation is complete. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 3):

The `animate` function accepts a callback that will be executed once the animation is complete. You can do something like this:

```
$(".gototop").click(function(){ 
    var focusElement = $("#contents");
    ScrollToTop(focusElement, function() { focusElement.focus(); }); 
}); 

function ScrollToTop(el, callback) { 
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(el).offset().top - 50 }, 'slow', callback);
}
```